# How to process multiple CSV files from an Amazon S3 bucket in a lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In an Amazon S3 bucket, event logs are sent as a CSV file every hour. I would like to perform some brief descriptive analysis on 1 weeks worth of data, every week (e.g. 168 files every week). The point of the analysis is to output a list of trending products for each week. I have a python script written out on my local machine which retrieves the latest 168 files from S3 using boto3, and does all the necessary wrangling etc.

But now I need to put this into a lambda function. I will set up an eventbridge to trigger the lambda function every monday. But, is it possible to call multiple files into a lambda function using the standard boto3, or do I need to do something special when defining the lambda handler function?

Here is the code from my local machine for getting the 168 files:

```
# import modules
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# set up aws credentials
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                      aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

# name s3 bucket
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_with_data')

# get names of last weeks files from s3 bucket
files = []

for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    files.append(file.key)

files = files[-168:]  # all files from last 7 days (24 files * 7 days per week)

bucket_name = 'bucket_with_data'

data = []

col_list = ["user_id", "event_type", "event_time", "session_id", "event_properties.product_id"]

for obj in files:
    csv_obj = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj)
    body = csv_obj['Body']
    csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8')
    temp = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
    final_list = list(set(col_list) & set(temp.columns))
    temp = temp[final_list]
    data.append(temp)

# combining all dataframes into one
event_data = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

So, my question is, can I just put this code into a lambda function and it should work, or do I need to incorporate a lambda_handler function? If I need to use a lambda_handler function, how would I handle multiple files? Because the lambda is being triggered by a schedule, rather than one event taking place.

Comment: I suggest that your code stores a JSON index object in S3 detailing which files have already been processed, so that you can only process new ones and don't need to rely on there always being a static number of objects to process - depending on exactly when the lambda runs, there may be 167, 168 or 169 objects to process. Also this helps with testing as you can run the lambda more frequently to test out the process. The lambda function should be granted permissions to access the bucket, so then you shouldn't need to store the credentials in the function itself.

Comment: @pbarber that is a good idea, thanks!

Comment: There's a very basic example [here](https://github.com/pbarber/ni-covid-tweets/blob/19eba61cdce07200d7876e3668ff04f089bf9512/sam/shared/__init__.py#L5) of a Python class that uses boto to read and write a Python dictionary as JSON to s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a Lambda function handler, otherwise it's not a Lambda function.

The Lambda runtime is looking for a specific entry point in your code and it will invoke that entry point with a specific set of parameters (event, context).

You can ignore the event and context if you choose to and simply use the boto3 SDK to list objects in a given S3 bucket (assuming your Lambda has permission to do this, via an IAM role), and then perform whatever actions you need to against those objects.

Your code example explicitly supplies boto3 with an access key and secret key, but that is not the best practice in AWS Lambda (or EC2 or other compute environment running on AWS). Instead, configure the Lambda function to assume an IAM role (that provides the necessary permissions).

Be aware of the Lambda function timeout, and increase it as necessary if you are going to process a lot of files. Increasing the RAM size is also potentially a good idea as it will give you correspondingly more CPU and network bandwidth.

If you're going to process a very large number of files then consider using [S3 Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html).

Comment: So I would include the def lambda_handler(event, context):
      etc. etc. etc.

But I would populate it with my normal python code above, and not refer to event and context?

Comment: As I understand your question, that's correct. Think of the Lambda function handler like `main(argc, argv)` in traditional programming.